# Update/ Add Nested Data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm working with BeautifulSoup/Python to parse an HTML page and update the content as required. A dummy structure of my HTML page structure is as follows:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="class_1">
<p><br/></p>
<div class="panel">Some content here </div>
<div class="panel">Another content here </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to update the content of `<div class="class_1">`.
I'm able to successfully use BeautifulSoup parser to get the contents of `<div class="class_1">`. I'm also able to save the new data that I would like to have in my HTML page as list as displayed below:

```
['<div class="panel">Some content here </div>', 
'<div class="panel">Updated new content here </div>', 
'<div class="panel">Hello new div here! </div>']
```

How can I get the following? I tried replace_with but it replaces `<` with `&lt;` which isn't desirable and I'm not too familiar with Beautiful soup so not sure what other options are available that can help me achieve the following.

```
<div class="main">
<div class="class_1">
<p><br/></p>
<div class="panel">Some content here </div>
<div class="panel">Updated new content here </div>
<div class="panel">Hello new div here! </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have already tired.

Comment: I have already mentioned them in the question. I was able to parse and get the existing contents of div class_1 and also able to gather the new data in list format that I would like to replace under that div. All I'm stuck at is how to replace in the content in the parsed div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="main">
<div class="class_1">
<p><br/></p>
<div class="panel">Some content here </div>
<div class="panel">Another content here </div>
</div>
</div>
"""

new_content = [
    '<div class="panel">Some content here </div>',
    '<div class="panel">Updated new content here </div>',
    '<div class="panel">Hello new div here! </div>',
]

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# locate the correct <p> element:
p = soup.select_one(".class_1 p")

# delete old content:
# tags:
for t in p.find_next_siblings():
    t.extract()
# text (if any):
for t in p.find_next_siblings(text=True):
    t.extract()

# place new content:
p.insert_after(BeautifulSoup("\n" + "\n".join(new_content) + "\n", "html.parser"))

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="class_1">
<p><br/></p>
<div class="panel">Some content here </div>
<div class="panel">Updated new content here </div>
<div class="panel">Hello new div here! </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and providing the hint. Much appreciated! The insert command provided by you did the trick for me... That is all I was actually looking for. Thanks again :)